# How can i show .pdf file in a dialog box in my website

Tags: php, html, pdf

I want to add a pdf file that will be shown to user, not in another tab but in a dialog box of website. ( I don't even want to add a download link. )

Comment: I had tried google doc viewer, pdf to html converter,pdf to doc conveter and then saving doc file as .html but these doesn't work perfect.

Comment: If you want to show a pdf, show it, do not convert it. Conversion will always introduce a loss of quality.

Answer (score 1):

You can show a pdf in an iframe. So your dialog box must contain an iframe with the pdf.

Comment: Will this code work ?  <iframe src="http://samplepdf.com/ sample.pdf" width="800px" height="600px" >

Comment: @SukantSharma The iframe code looks good, but how do you show your dialog box ? You must use a javascript generated html dialog box. If you want the browser show a dialog box with a pdf. It is impossible.

Comment: I just tried this but it's not showing pdf file.  <body> <iframe src="1.pdf"> </body>

Comment: Did you close the iframe tag? is the url correct ? Why isn't it showing your file ?

Comment: Yes i closed it </iframe> and url is perfect. It just show a blank frame.

Comment: Now it works <iframe src="1.pdf" width="100%" height="1000px"> 
It was not working because iframe Height was not matching with the pdf. And thankyou so much.